# has_many through form not registering in the join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have a problem with my ruby on rails 4 app with the activeadmin gem
I have generated multiple resources that works well but I have a problem with a resource that has a has_many through relationship. The new records are not registered through the join table.

Here is my model :

video.rb

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :album_videos
  has_many :albums, :through => :album_videos
end
```

Album.rb

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :album_videos
  has_many :videos, :through => :album_videos
end
```

Album_video.rb

```
class AlbumVideo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :video
  belongs_to :album
end
```

And the activeadmin file for album
album.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Album do

  menu :priority => 6, :label => proc{ "Album de vidéos" }
  filter :album_videos
    permit_params :titre, :description, videos_attributes: [:id, :titre, :_update,:_create]

  form do |f|
    f.inputs
    f.inputs "Vidéos" do
      f.input :videos, as: :check_boxes, collection: Video.all, :member_label => :titre
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

Album's form is well displayed, I have a panel with all my registered videos.
When I create a new album, the album is registered but nothing in the album_videos table.

Anything I am missing ?

Comment: Not familiar with active admin. But i think you want http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: @DickieBoy I tried adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for :album_videos, allow_destroy: true` to my album.rb but it doesn't fix it

Comment: You would need a little more than than, for example the `fields_for` should be `:album_videos` maybe this is more what you need: http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes

Comment: Ok, I think I advanced on this. I think my model is right because I can create the link manually. I think the problem comes from activeadmin. I will check on this. Anyway, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You juste have to add

```
video_ids: []
```

to your permit_params.
Mine looks like this now :

```
permit_params :titre, :description, video_ids: []
```